# Object On Stage Cannot Be Accessed From External Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an external ActionScript class, which is called Menu.as, trying to access objects on the stage using the following code:

```
MovieClip(parent).fullmenu_mc.x = 80;
```

Although the program compiles, I get Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

I don't see how this is possible since the object is already on the stage and just needs to be accessed. Am I somehow accessing the object incorrectly?

I also tried the following code inside Menu.as:

```
import EngineClass;
var engine : EngineClass = new EngineClass();
engine.fullmenu_mc.x = 80;
```

which gives the same runtime error. Any thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Seems like `fullmenu_mc` does not exist.

Comment: That's what the error makes it seem like, but its there on the stage the whole time... checked the instance, everything seems correct

Comment: loop through the display list and trace the name of all objects.

Comment: Also try doing `var parent:MovieClip = MovieClip(parent);` on one line, then `var fullmenu_mc:* = parent.fullmenu_mc;` and finally `fullmenu_mc.x = 80;` on a third line.  Breaking it up will help you localize the error.

Comment: Why isn't anyone telling the Asker about using `public static` variables? Or am I wrong about that being a solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help, no luck though. BotMaster, looks like looping through the display list still produces the same 1009 object is null error, and the same with the code you mentioned in your comment. VC.One, not sure I follow regarding static...

Answer (score 0):

**Short Version:**

Basically you first need to setup a variable that acts a reference name to your on-stage movieclip. You can instead make it a `public static` variable if you want other Class files imported to also control this variable (and therefore also the movieclip) from their own Class code.

So define a `public static var menuMC : MovieClip = new MovieClip();`
 then when Stage + stage items is available (since Flash processes code first then makes a Stage + items after), we update definition to know the instance name of on-stage object it represents by saying:
 `menuMC = DisplayObjectContainer(getChildByName("fullmenu_mc")) as MovieClip;`

Now you can update via any imported external class using a line like: `Main.menuMC.x = 200;` (where **Main** is the name of Class that holds the definition of what **menuMC** means).

**Long Version:**

Assuming you have some setup like this.

- `fullmenu_mc` = instance name of Object on stage
- Main.as = your FLA's document Class file attached to hold the main running code
- External.as = some other external Class file that will also control the 
  on-stage MC

**Note:** If your code is on the timeline instead of a (Main.as) document class let me know to update (if possible), but the above Classes setup would be easier...

In **Main.as**.. (define variable and also run a function that is inside external Class)

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import External;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var  ExtClass : External = new External; //init the external class
        public static var menuMC : MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //reference to on-stage MC


        public function Main () 
        {
            if (stage != null) { Init(); } //do Init function if SWF loaded ok...
            else { addEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init); } //or do the function when ready..

        }

        //If stage is available then we can now do this
        public function Init (event:Event = null) :void
        {
            //update menuMC to know it means some item "X" on stage. "X" is instance name 
            menuMC = DisplayObjectContainer(getChildByName("fullmenu_mc")) as MovieClip; 

            trace("menuMC is type : " + menuMC); //if ok then traces [object MovieClip]

            menuMC.x = 10; //just for testing
            ExtClass.accessTest(); //run some function in External class

        }


    }

}
```

Now in **External.as** we can control the `fullmenu_mc` (now known as **menuMC**) like so..

```
public function accessTest () :void 
{
    //access stage item using Static Variable from Main Class
    Main.menuMC.x += 500;
    trace("Full_menu... new x-pos is : " + Main.menuMC.x);

}
```

Comment: Thanks VC.one, extremely well written answer and easy to follow as well! I have it set up as classes like you mentioned, no code on timeline. Code compiles perfectly, however when the function inside External.as is called, I get Error #1069: Property fullmenu_mc not found on com.objects.Menu and there is no default value. I don't even know where to begin with that... (com.objects.Menu is the name and location of my external class)

Comment: Looking at the Main.as code I posted, what did you replace `public static var menuMC` with? That becomes the variable name you must use in Menu.as to access the movieclip. Also `Property fullmenu_mc not found` seems strange. Can you post the line that causes the error please?